# Is FullGraphics an abandoned function? Is there an alternative?

Tags: graphics, functions, bugs, language-design, backslide

[`FullGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullGraphics.html) hasn't worked entirely for a long time and the situation appears to be getting worse instead of better.  In *Mathematica* 10.0, 10.1, 11.3, 12.3 up to 13.1 a simple usage throws numerous errors and returns a graphic without ticks and with the wrong aspect ratio:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}] // FullGraphics
```

> Axes::axes: {{False,False},{False,False}} is not a valid axis
> specification. >>
>
> Ticks::ticks: {Automatic,Automatic} is not a valid tick specification. >>
>
> (* etc. etc. *)

This may be caused by or related to [More Ticks::ticks errors in AbsoluteOptions in v10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68937/).

It seems that I must go back to version 5 functionality if I want this function to work right:

```
<< Version5`Graphics`  (* load old graphics subsystem *)

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}] // FullGraphics
```

[image]

I wonder at this point if there is any indication that `FullGraphics` and perhaps also `AbsoluteOptions` are still supported?  Or has something to the contrary has been written (Wolfram blog, a developer's comment, etc.) that indicates these should be removed from the documentation now?

With `FullGraphics` broken is there a method that can take its place for producing proper `Graphics` directives that may be further manipulated and combined, not merely vectorized outlines?

Comment: Good question. (IOU one upvote.) When I made the jump from version 5 to 8, it was one of the differences that struck me, since it broke some of my tricks, and thus had to resort to alternatives. So it has become even less useful now, it seems.

Comment: When you find an answer, you might want to add a post in the http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43631/most-influential-and-or-disrupting-features-introduced-with-new-versions-of-math thread.

Comment: @Peltio I never saw that question until now.  I started and maintain one that is fairly similar: [(56728)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56728/121).  I hope the emphasis of these questions is different enough that mine is not a duplicate.  (I seek to extend missing documentation as it were.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I updated the wiki contribution to emphasize the difference between that post and yours, and added a link to it and to WRI list of incompatible changes (which I swear was not there when I started the wiki :-) ). I do not see duplicates.

Comment: How related is this code: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}] /. {HoldPattern[Frame -> _] -> 
    Frame -> False} // FullGraphics`

Comment: @JunhoLee That helps!  It behaves more like it did in version 7, which while flawed was still useful.  I am surprised as the `Plot` by default does not have a frame.  Apparently the internal `Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, False}}` is not handled well by `FullGraphics`, but that's kind of the point of this question: it seems no one is maintaining this function any longer.

Comment: The problem persist in 11.3 and the function hasn't been removed from the documentation. The developers are aware of the issue and there is an ongoing support case. 
*CASE:3897155*.

Comment: As of Mathematica 12.1 this is still an issue. Did you find any new workarounds?

Comment: @Qbyte sorry to say I did not.

Comment: I don't have the v13.0, but using a basic cloud account, the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQq6D.png) shows that it is still unchanged.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the problem appeared in the version 5-> 6 transition.

```
<< Version6`Graphics`
InputForm@ListPlot[{{0, 0}}]
(* Graphics[{...
Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, False}},...] *)
```

which has the same form in later version.
This subtle difference is causing the trouble. c.f.

```
 << Version5`Graphics`
InputForm@ListPlot[{{0, 0}}]
(* Graphics[{...
Frame -> False,...] *)
```

This bug can thus be circumvented by manually changing this value.

```
FullGraphics @@ (InputForm[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4}]] /. 
Rule[Frame, _ ] -> 
Rule[Frame, False])
```

Answer (score 6):

### Basic implementation

After working on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271580/280) answer, I realized that the undocumented [`` FrontEnd`ExportPacket ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1411/280) with `"InputForm"` as second argument may be considered as an alternative to `FullGraphics`. First, a basic definition:

```
fullGraphicsBasic[expr_, dist_ : 1.2] := Block[{e = dist}, ToExpression[
   First@FrontEndExecute[
     FrontEnd`ExportPacket[Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes[expr]], "InputForm"]]]]
```

Here is a demonstration of how `fullGraphicsBasic` works (*Mathematica* 13.1.0):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}]
fullGraphicsBasic[%]
ResourceFunction["ShortInputForm"][%]
```

> [image: plot]

> [image: fullGraphicsBasic@plot]

> [image: screenshot]

The axes and ticks look lighter than they are on the original figure due to the default `Antialiasing -> True` applied to the graphics primitives (by default `Axes` and `Frame` are rendered with `Antialiasing -> False`). We can fix this, for example, as follows:

```
fullGraphicsBasic[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}]] /. 
 AbsoluteThickness[0.2`] :> Sequence[AbsoluteThickness[0.2`], Antialiasing -> False]
```

> [image: plot]

---

### Discussion and better implementation

I was forced to wrap the main code of `fullGraphicsBasic` with `Block`, because for some reason it returns an expression with undefined variable `e`, which determines the distance between the minus sign and the number. The minus signs are separately drawn as `Style["-", FontFamily -> "MathematicaSans"]`, while the numbers are drawn with `FontFamily -> "Arial"`. Surprisingly, the "Hyphen-Minus" characters `"-"` look the same (at least on Windows 10 x64) in these fonts, so this complication is completely redundant. But it makes a trouble, because the correct value for this variable seemingly depends on where the number is placed on the plot. The same problem applies to some other mathematical characters, for example: `~`, `±`, `=` etc. Applying `PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}` doesn't change this behavior.

This feature/bug is present in all versions I checked: 8.0.4, 12.3.1 and 13.1.0, excepting version 5.2 where the method itself doesn't quite work. It is interesting, that if I specify `"Output"` as a style for the `Cell` in the definition above, this undefined variable `e` disappears and the result looks as if it is replaced with `1.8` (as a consequence, the minus sign runs over the number). These observations indicate that this functionality of `` FrontEnd`ExportPacket `` is still incomplete.

As a workaround to this horrible feature, one can replace the "Hyphen-Minus" character with zero before applying `` FrontEnd`ExportPacket ``, and then replace it back after it. Since we are most interested in reproducing the `Ticks` and `FrameTicks`, we can proceed as follows:

```
Clear[fullGraphics]
fullGraphics[expr_] := Module[{e},
   e = expr /. 
     g_Graphics :> 
      Show[g, AbsoluteOptions[g, {Ticks, FrameTicks}] /. 
        s_String :> 
         StringReplace[
          s, {StartOfString ~~ "-." -> "00.", StartOfString ~~ "-" -> "0"}]];
   ToExpression[
     First@FrontEndExecute[
       FrontEnd`ExportPacket[Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes[e]], "InputForm"]]] /. 
    Text[Style[s_String, opts__], c__] :> 
     Text[Style[Row[{Invisible["0"], 
         StringReplace[
          s, {StartOfString ~~ "0" ~~ d : DigitCharacter :> "\[Minus]" <> d}]}], opts], 
      c]];
```

Answer (score 3):

### News about `FullGraphics` and `AbsoluteOptions`

This CW answer is intended for collecting the ongoing information about changes in `FullGraphics` and `AbsoluteOptions` through the versions.

---

> I wonder at this point if there is any indication that `FullGraphics` and perhaps also `AbsoluteOptions` are still supported?

In version 13.0 was ["substantially updated implementation"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn130.html) of `AbsoluteOptions`, and later after update in version 13.1 it ["can resolve more 2D and 3D graphics options"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn131.html). Detailed information is not provided in the documentation, but at least now the [long-standing bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18034/280) in determining `PlotRange` via `AbsoluteOptions` is fixed. Also, the  "Incompatible Changes" page has a [notice for version 13.0](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html#447496873):

> `AbsoluteOptions` has been reimplemented to be more accurate, and the form returned for a particular option may be different now.

It is also worth mentioning that there is [`ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GraphicsInformation) which allows to obtain the true absolute values for some `Graphics` options even in the versions before version 13.0.

Concerning `FullGraphics`, [rhermans](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/10397/rhermans) [reported here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83648/is-fullgraphics-an-abandoned-function-is-there-an-alternative/271611#comment457327_83648) at May 29, 2018:

> The developers are aware of the issue and there is an ongoing support case. CASE:3897155. – rhermans May 29, 2018 at 16:35

But I don't see any improvement in behavior of `FullGraphics` up to version 13.1. Probably this bug has low priority due to low number of bug reports.

To the above, it should be added that in version 12.3 `AxisObject` was added, which greatly facilitates the reconstruction of the plot axes based on the information that can be obtained through `AbsoluteOptions`.