# Error in FullGraphics V10.1

Tags: graphics

Error in `FullGraphics`.

```
FullGraphics[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: related: [Is FullGraphics an abandoned function"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83648/125)

Comment: @kguler thanks for link. This question is a duplicate:)

Comment: @Algohi maybe you could just delete your question at this point.