# How to sample points randomly below a curve?

Tags: random, sampling

How can I randomly select 1000 points uniformly from the shaded area below the plotted curve?

```
Plot[1/π Cos[θ]^2, {θ, 0, 2 π}, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

Comment: One simple way is to sample points uniformly both above and below the curve, and keep only the latter.

Comment: Given the symmetries, if (x,y) is above the curve you can replace it with ((x+π/2) mod 2π, 1/π - y).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As noted in my comment, one approach is as follows.  First, generate thousands of pairs of random numbers in the range `{0, 2 π}`, `{0, 1/π}`.  Then select the first 1000 that lie below the curve.

```
lst = Transpose@{RandomReal[{0, 2 π}, 4000], RandomReal[{0, 1/π}, 4000]};
listsel = Select[lst, #[[2]] < 1/π Cos[#[[1]]]^2 &, 1000];
Show[Plot[1/π Cos[θ]^2, {θ, 0, 2 π}, Filling -> Bottom], ListPlot[listsel]]
```

[image]

This simple process works well provided the portion of points selected is a reasonable fraction of the total number of points, as it is here.

Answer (score 48):

There is no need in filtering out random points in a rectangle that don't fall in the prescribed region. The sampling within a region can be done directly with `RandomPoint`.

Specify the region:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 2 Pi && 0 <= y <= 1/Pi Cos[x]^2, {x, y}]
```

and then one can sample a point with

```
RandomPoint[reg]
```

> e.g., {0.39486, 0.0422331}

or several points `n` with `RandomPoint[reg, n]`. There's a warning about an unbounded region, so to keep it clean one can add bounds as a third argument to `RegionPlot`:

```
data = RandomPoint[reg, 1000, {{0, 2 Pi}, {0, 1/Pi}}];

Show[RegionPlot[reg], ListPlot[data, Frame -> True], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT** as per [Trilarion's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131755/how-to-sample-points-randomly-below-a-curve/131762?noredirect=1#comment355855_131762):

How does `RandomPoint` work internally is beyond my knowledge, but the timing analysis shows that it does not sample a rectangle and throw away the points that don't fall in the region (and even if it does, it's a way faster implementation):

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 10 && y >= x && y <= x + 1, {x, y}]
```

[image]

[bbgodfrey's `Select` method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131756/22013):

```
n = 110000;
(lst = Transpose@{RandomReal[{0, 10}, n], RandomReal[{0, 11}, n]};
  sel = Select[lst, #[[1]] <= #[[2]] <= #[[1]] + 1 &, 
    UpTo[10000]];) // AbsoluteTiming
Length@sel
```

> {0.221189, Null}
>
> 9916

10000 points weren't even generated.

`RandomPoint` approach:

```
pts = RandomPoint[reg, 10000, {{0, 10}, {0, 11}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.049927, Null}

More than 4x faster, and all 10000 desired points are obviously generated.

Comment: "There is no need in filtering out random points in a rectangle that don't fall in the prescribed region. The sampling within a region can be done directly with RandomPoint." Isn't it kind of doing the same as filtering out random points internally? Or how does RandomPoint work?

Comment: perhaps, it first parametrizes the implicit region in a [0,1]x[0,1] topologically equivalent object and then does non-uniform sampling. This should be faster, but you need to take into account for the differential area change between the original region and the parametrization.

Comment: @Trilarion, one does not necessarily have to do rejection sampling; see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57938) for instance.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the link. The answers there are great.

Answer (score 19):

More of a first principles approach, use the function as a `PDF` to generate random `x` data, then for each `x` choose a uniformly distributed point on the vertical line `{x, f[x]}`:

```
f[x_] := 1/π Cos[x]^2
z = Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2 π}]; (*can use NIntegrate here if needed*)
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Point[
   {#, First@RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, f[#]}], 1]} & /@ 
    RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[f[x]/z, {x, 0, 2 π}], 1000]
  ]
]
```

[image]

This is likely the fastest approach.

I think newer versions of `ProbabilityDistribution` may do that normalization (`/z`) automatically, btw.

Answer (score 10):

In case where only the plot is given:

```
plot = Plot[1/π Cos[θ]^2, {θ, 0, 2 π}, Filling -> Bottom]
```

```
polygons = Cases[plot // Normal, _Polygon, ∞]
region = RegionUnion @@ polygons;
pts = RandomPoint[region, 100]; (*quite slow*)
Show[plot, Graphics@Point@pts]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting application of `Normal`.  Perhaps `Normal` is the answer the question regarding an alternative for FullGraphics ( http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83648/is-fullgraphics-an-abandoned-function-is-there-an-alternative).

Comment: @LouisB Probably not, it only converts `GraphicsComplex` to regular primitives.