# How to superimpose plots and graphics in the same coordinate system?

Tags: graphics

**NB:** I am aware that "plots" are graphics too, so the title would be more precisely worded if "graphics" were replaced by "non-plot graphics".

---

**EDIT:** I have edited my original example to make the problems with the solutions proposed so far more evident.

---

For example, let `plot` be this plot:

```
plot = Plot[{0.5 Cos[4 Pi x], x}, {x, 0, 0.5}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

...and `graphic` be this disk:

```
graphic = Graphics[{LightGray, Disk[{-1, -0.25}, 0.2]}, ImageSize -> Tiny, Frame->True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to superimpose `plot` and `graphic` so that

1. they share the same coordinate system (including aspect ratio)
2. all the components of `plot` and `graphics` (*including axes, frames, tick-marks, etc.*) are represented in the resulting image.

### More generally, **I want to superimpose an arbitrary sequence of plots and graphics so that the two requirements above are satisfied.**

Although this follows directly from (1), let me explicitly state that the ordering of the items in the sequence of plots and graphics should have no effect in the relative placement of the superimposed items.

---

The `Overlay` command meets requirement 2 only:

```
Overlay[{graphic, plot}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**IMPORTANT:** Even though the placement and proportions it produces are completely off, `Overlay` gets right the aspect of ***faithfully preserving*** the axes, frames, ticks, etc. of its components.

---

The `Show` command meets requirement 1 only:

```
Show[{graphic, plot}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The frame in `Show`'s output is spurious: it does not correspond to `graphic`'s original frame.  Furthermore, `plot`'s axes are gone.

A more subtle (and serious) problem with `Show` is that it is not commutative:

```
Show[{plot, graphic}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this example, flipping the order of items in the call to `Show` causes one of the items is no longer shown.

---

The result from `Show` looks much closer to the desired result, but is missing `plot`'s axes, ticks, etc.

IOW, `plot`'s contribution to the final result should look like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Note, in particular, the extents of the axes.**

---

**NB:** In this example, the x and y coordinates are scaled equally on the screen (and, therefore, in the desired final result, `graphic`'s disk looks circular and `plot`'s orange line has a 45-degree angle on the screen).  In general, however, the scaling of the x and y coordinates need not be equal.  The only requirement is that the scaling, whatever it is, applies equally to both `plot` and `graphic`.

Comment: `Show[plot, graphic, PlotRange -> All, plot[[2]]]`?

Comment: Instead of `plot[[2]]`, `Options[plot]` can also be used.

Comment: Neither of the solutions offered deal with the general case (which I've just made more prominent in the post).

Comment: What you need is `FullGraphics` but it seems to be a [abandoned function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83648/5467). I have tried a little bit to use it for your problem but it is not satisfactory

Comment: @andre: IMHO, *Mathematica* is becoming less and less useful with every new version :/  .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem you will run into by keeping the frame/axis ticks & labels is that the space outside of the bounds of the frame/axis is not measured in the coordinate space of the graphic. It is instead measured in printer (or desktop publishing) points.

`Inset` can inset a graphic sized to the coordinate space but that size includes the space padded on (in printer points) to make room for the frame/axis ticks & labels.  A method to convert this printer points padding into units of the coordinate space such that it would be useful to `Inset` is not immediately clear.

However, if you were willing to forgo some tick labels with the option to support their absence by a frame then you can achieve the superimposition.

```
superimposeGraphics[graphics_List, opts : OptionsPattern[Graphics]] :=
 Graphics[
  With[{rng = First@Values@AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange]},
     Inset[#, rng[[All, 1]], rng[[All, 1]], Flatten[Differences /@ rng]]
     ] & /@ (Show[#, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
       PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> None] & /@ graphics)
  ,
  opts,
  PlotRange -> (MapThread[#1[#2] &, {{Min, Max}, #}] & /@
     Transpose[
      Flatten[Values@AbsoluteOptions[graphics, PlotRange], 1], {3, 1, 2}])
  ]
```

`superimposeGraphics` removes the `PlotRangePadding` (in coordinate space units) and `ImagePadding` (in printer points) from the graphics. The graphic is now bounded by its frame and only contains its plot range.`ImageMargins` could also be set to zero if you like. The `AspectRatio` to `Automatic` so that no stretching will occur from the inset sizing.  Now these can be `Inset` into the graphic and sized to the coordinate space of the enclosing `Graphics`. The `PlotRange` is set to include all graphics.

```
superimposeGraphics[{plot, graphic}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
superimposeGraphics[{plot, graphic}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) or [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

```
Plot[{0.5 Cos[4 Pi x], x}, {x, 0, 0.5},
 ImageSize -> Small,
 Prolog -> {LightGray, Disk[{0.45, -0.25}, 0.2]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.65}, {-0.5, 0.5}},
 AspectRatio -> 1/0.65]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
Show[graphic, plot,  PlotRange -> All, plot[[2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[ graphic, plot, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, plot[[2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As noted by @C.E. in a comment, you can also use `Options[plot]` instead of `plot[[2]]`.

If it is *OK if some items obscure others*, then as noted by @AlbertRetey in a comment, you just need

```
Show[plot, graphic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: if you change the order you won't need the addition of `plot[[2]]`. The convention is (not sure whether that is documented or not) that the options of the first graphics are used unless they are explicitly overwritten with options. So `Show[{plot, graphic}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]` will work as well.

Comment: just looked it up: from the documentation of `Show`: "The lists of non-default options in the g_i are concatenated."

Comment: @AlbertRetey, you are right, Show takes the unspecified options from the first argument. Not sure if this what the OP asked, but the reason I  did not change the order of `graphic` and `plot` is to have disk appear below the plot lines.

Comment: yes, that is a problem I also just have seen. I don't exactly remember why, but I got into the habit of using `Prolog` and `Epilog` in such cases, maybe it was because of these peculiarities with `Show`...

Comment: @kglr: It's ok if some items obscure others.

Comment: You might check if my answer to [(83636)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138985/45431) satisfies your needs.