# How to use "For" or other tool to plot points in a gragh?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Try a simple example about bifurcarion. The codes in MM are as follows:

```
Block[{x = 0.2}, For[u = 2.9, u < 3, u = u + 0.05,  For[i = 0, i < 30, i++,   {x1 = u x (1 - x);    x = x1;    if[i > 10, ListPlot[{u, x}]]    }]]]
```

[image]

I find it does'not work. The objective is to draw a gragh like this:
[image]

The code is fine in the matlab:

[image]

But I don't know what's the problem in Mathmatica. Hope someone genius could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5123/bifurcation-diagram-for-1d-map

Comment: The first code piece doesn't work probably because you're reading a text book based on version 5.2 or earlier. Have a look at this Chinese tutorial: https://note.youdao.com/ynoteshare1/index.html?id=0c2719208239696d61182199327bd38c&type=note (There should be related posts in this site too, but I fail to dig it out. )

Comment: OK I manage to find two: 1. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47123/1871 2.  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43670/1871 BTW the `if` is clearly wrong, it should be `If`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard method and compare with what you want. Standard code

```
X = Compile[{{u, _Real}}, ({u, #} &) /@
                Union[Drop[NestList[u # (1 - #) &, .2, 300], 100]]];

ListPlot[Flatten[Table[X[u], {u, 2.6, 4, .0001}], 1], 
 PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[.0005], Frame -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Your code

```
X1 = Compile[{{u, _Real}}, ({u, #} &) /@
                Union[Drop[NestList[u # (1 - #) &, .2, 18], 9]]];

ListPlot[Flatten[Table[X1[u], {u, 2.6, 4, .0001}], 1], 
 PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[.0005], Frame -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Standard (left) and your code (right)
[image: Figure 1]