# Tools to help upgrade old notebooks?

Tags: notebooks, upgrade

Version revisions of many applications provide upgrade scripts to, for example, database tables upon which those applications rely.  Indeed, back in the day, when providing new language features for the PLATO network, I wrote a program that went through all source code of all users and converted them to work with the new version of TUTOR. While I am aware of the fact that Mathematica is far more sophisticated as a programming language, and therefore completely automated upgrades are not feasible, there must be many routine tasks that could be automated.

Are there any such scripts written in any language(s)?

Comment: I do not know of a tool other than manual editing to make the notebook work in new versions. But these links might help.  [Most influential and/or disrupting features introduced with new versions of Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43631/most-influential-and-or-disrupting-features-introduced-with-new-versions-of-math) and [Graphics incompatibilities between Mathematica Versions](https://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaVersions.html) and [Incompatible Changes since Mathematica Version 1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html)

Comment: It will also help to mention which version of Mathematica you want to upgrade your notebook from. I have new idea what PLATO is and what TUTOTR is and how these are related to Mathematica in your question.

Comment: Your references are very helpful.  Thanks, Nasser.

As for PLATO/TUTOR -- I merely included that reference as kind of an inside joke with the folks at Wolfram.  PLATO was a precursor to the Internet created at the University of Illinois way back in the 60s and 70s.  Its only _really_ related in the sense that TUTOR was a programming language that had a lot of idiosyncrasies.